# How to addActionLister to button in Static method

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

I have a problem in how to addActionListener for a button in static method

here is my static method

```
private static void initComponents() {


    btnExit = new JButton("Exit");
    btnExit.addActionListener(this);  <==== this is error


}
```

do you guys have any idea
in how to add a listener so that the button response when clicked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since it is a static method, there is no `this`. You can use several options here: anonymous class, new instance of a class which implements `ActionListener`, ... .

Some sample code which uses the anonymous class

```
  btnExit.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent aActionEvent ) {
      //do something here
    }
  } );
```

You might want to read [this article](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) about static methods/variables and [this article](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html) about the `this` keyword as well to obtain a better understanding on why `this` will not work in a static context